# SPICE Modeling voltage during battery discharge

Tags: batteries, voltage, spice

I am trying to create a spice model of a battery discharging into an LED.

[image]

I would like to model the charge remaining (Ah) throughout the discharge and as I understand it this can be acheived by reading the voltage across the terminals of the battery.

I would like to model the discharging of the battery and view the voltage across the terminals over time.

I am just starting to use spice models and have been playing around with pspice, ltspice and now circuit-lab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good model of a battery would keep it as a voltage source, but add a resistance in series with it (separate from your external 220R resistor).

Then you need to find a way of increasing that resistance as the product of current draw and time increases.